# How to calculate $|1,1\rangle \otimes |1,-1\rangle=\alpha|2,0\rangle+\beta|1,0\rangle+\gamma|0,0\rangle$ for $\mathfrak{su}(2)$?

Tags: lie-algebras, physics

At $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, tensor product $3 \otimes 3$ can be decomposed to
$3\otimes3=5\oplus3\oplus1$.

In this space, $|1,1\rangle \otimes |1,-1\rangle$ has weight $0$.

So we should be able to write down
$$|1,1\rangle \otimes |1,-1\rangle=\alpha|2,0\rangle+\beta|1,0\rangle+\gamma|0,0\rangle.$$

How to calculate $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$?

Comment: The answer depends on the normalizations. I can guess that $|m,n\rangle$ stands for **some** vector of weight $n$ of the $m$-dimensional rep (that all algebraists want to call $V(m-1)$, the irreducible rep with highest weight $m-1$). But, I don't know **which** vector of that 1-dimensional subspace this refers to, so it is difficult to get started.

Comment: In the eyes of algebraists, physicists use really pervese notation in rep theory. As if the dimension of a representation where a *natural* parameter :-)

Comment: Oops. Looks like for you $|m.n\rangle$ is a vector of $V(m)$. No, this was supposed to be the 3-dimensional irrep. Confused :-(

Comment: But more importantly, a standard basis of  $V(m)$, usually defines by how the ladder operators act on them, is not unique. There is a constant multiplier that can be chosen arbitrarily. Usually we start from the highest weight vector, and the rest are determined recursvely in relation to that. But the scaling parameter of that highest weight vector is arbitrary. Implying that $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ can be anything unless you specify which vector of the tensor product is the highest weight vector of is the one that generates a standard basis.

Comment: Meaning that the only possible answer is in terms of writing that tensor product as a sum of weight vectors belonging to one of the three component representation.

Comment: Anyway, if $|1,1\rangle$ and $|1,-1\rangle$ are both weight vectors of the 3-dimension rep (that I call $V(2)$, but that has weights $2,0,-2$ by the conventions in algebra), then I am totally at loss with your notation

Comment: Sorry about several typos. Getting late, and I have had some fine single malt!

Comment: Can you please list the weight vectors of the 3-dimensional representation according to the conventions your teacher is using, and how the ladder operators act on them?

Comment: ueir: You mean $3\otimes 3 \simeq 5 \oplus 3 \oplus 1$, right? @Jyrki: Kippis! And happy new year.

Comment: @offline This question is about the Lie algebra, not the Lie group $\mathrm{SU}(2)$, so lower case is better. (And for matrix Lie groups please use `\mathrm`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply $\langle 2,0\mid$ on both sides so you get $\alpha$ on the right hand side (assuming standard normalization) and the inner product

$$
\langle 2,0 \mid 1,1 ; 1,-1 \rangle
$$

in the

$$
\langle J M \mid j_1 j_2 ; m_1 , m_2 \rangle
$$

notation. Now look at the [Clebsch-Gordan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients)  recurrence relations (the recursion @JyrkiLahtonen refers to).

This is the special case of $j_1=j_2=m_1=-m_2$ in the article. But check that you are using the same normalization convention as the article before using that to check your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are [given](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients#Special_cases), 4th relation,
$$  \langle  1 \, 1 \, 1 \, (- 1) | J \, 0 \rangle
  = 2  \sqrt{\frac{2 J + 1}{(J + 2   + 1)! (2   - J)!}}~~, $$
so read off, as instructed,
$$
\alpha=1/\sqrt{6}, \qquad \beta=1/\sqrt{2},\qquad \gamma=1/\sqrt{3}.
$$